# Formula to calculate file size of jpeg image after resizing

Tags: image

Given the file size (kb), width & height of original jpeg image file and the width & height of sized-down jpeg image, is there a way to calculate the file size of the sized-down image?

Here is a formula:

```
new_file_size = file_size_original * ((new_width/original_width) * (new_height/original_height))
```

For example, it is 5000kb, 3000 x 2000 for original jpeg file, if the new dimension is 1000 x 768, then the new file size is:

```
new_file_size = 5000 (kb) * (1000/3000) * (768/2000)
              = 640kb
```

Is the formula above making sense?

Comment: Not the same. Here the question is, given a image, resize it to a certain dimension, what's the file size of resized one? In the post, it is given a dimension of image, what's the max size of it.

Comment: @user938363 JPEG compression can be tuned, so you must also stipulate that the resized image uses the same compression parameters.

Comment: `biziclop`, yes, there is a image quality option for jpeg. Not sure what's the default if not set explicitly when saving jpeg.